# Somar valor no banco de dados

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Utilizo Codeigniter, e a situação é a seguinte: O produto tem um estoque atual, e quero fazer a entrada de mais itens deste estoque... como somo o já existente com as novas entradas? Segue código:

CONTROLLER:

```
 public function entrada(){
    $CI =& get_instance();
    if (esta_logado()):
        if(is_admin()):
            $this->form_validation->set_message('is_natural_no_zero', 'Escolha uma opção para o %s');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('id_produto','PRODUTO','required|is_natural_no_zero');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('estoque','ESTOQUE DE ENTRADA','required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('preco_compra','PREÇO DE COMPRA','required');
            if($this->form_validation->run()==TRUE):
                $dados['estoque_atual'] = $this->input->post('estoque');
                $dados['preco_compra'] = $this->input->post('preco_compra');
                $this->estoque->do_update($dados, array('id'=>$this->input->post('id_produto')));
            endif; 
            set_tema('conteudo', load_modulo('telas_estoque','entrada'));
            set_tema('footerinc', load_js(array('table')), FALSE);
            load_template();
        else:
             //set_msg('msgerro', 'Usuário não tem permissão','erro');
             redirect('home');
         endif;
    else:
        load_template();
    endif;  
}
```

MODEL:

```
 // Método -> Update item individual da estoque quando comprador
public function do_update($dados=NULL, $condicao=NULL, $redir=TRUE){
    if ($dados != NULL && is_array($condicao)):
        $this->db->update('produtos', $dados, $condicao);
        if ($this->db->affected_rows()>0):
            set_msg('msgok','Alteração efetuada com sucesso','sucesso');
        else:
            set_msg('msgerro','Erro ao atualizar dados','erro');
        endif;  
        if($redir) redirect(current_url());
    endif;
}
```

Quero adicionar o valor de estoque ao estoque_atual, como faço?

Comment: Tentou usar campo + 1?

Comment: mas se eu usar esse campo irá somar o valor "1" certo?

Comment: Sim ou então você pode fazer campo + $var, o que daria certo tb, basta ajustar o sql

Comment: Faço isso direto no model?

Comment: quando você dá um print_r($dados), o que lhe retorna?

Comment: retorna "1", valor do id que eu pego pra alterar no bd

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43016/discussion-between-andre-baill-and-sergio-henrique).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Controller**

```
$this->estoque->do_update($_POST, $this->input->post('id_produto'));
```

**No model:**

```
public function do_update($dados=NULL, $id=NULL, $redir=TRUE){ 
    if ($dados != NULL && $id != NULL): 
        $this->db->where('id', $id); 
        $this->db->update('produtos', "estoque_atual = estoque_atual + '".$dados['estoque_atual']."'"); 

        if ($this->db->affected_rows()>0): 
            set_msg('msgok',print_r($dados),'sucesso'); 
        else: 
            set_msg('msgerro',print_r($id),'erro'); 
        endif; 

        if($redir) redirect(current_url()); 
    endif; 
}
```